# black edges on shapeable imageview after corner round

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

After rounding the edges on my shapeable image view, I still get black edges around the rounded edges
[image: Image with black edges]

Here is my xml :

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/shapeableImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:shapeAppearance="@style/article_shape" />
```

Comment: Do you please add code of your @style/article_shape?

Comment: One of the parents has a black blackground.

Comment: This is the code for my style <style name="article_shape">
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">20dp</item>
        <item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">rounded</item>

Answer (score 2):

app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/article_shape"  actually worked. The black edges will not reflect when you run on an emulator or a device. Thanks

Comment: But when I take a screenshot via code, it still shows the black background in the bg of the bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Androidanifest.xml** file in the `Application` section of the `hardwareAccelerated` setting:

```
android:hardwareaccelerated="true"
```