# questions about circle shape imageview with ShapeableImageView in android

Tags: android, material-design

I found a couple answers to make a view circled with material ShapeableImageView like the code below.

[answer1](https://howtodoandroid.com/shapeableimageview-material-components-android)

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent" parent="">
            <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
        </style>
```

[answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66624415/shapeableimageview-doesnt-round-corners)

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.circleImageView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>
```

[answer3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61986850/13892944)

```
<style name="roundedImageViewRounded">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

then, this type of style is referenced by this attribute in material ShapeableImageView

> app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/correspondingStyleName"

I applied these and all works fine (besides the one from answer2 since its cornerFamily is cut rather than rounded). My point here is all work fine. However, to use the best practice out of these, I wonder a few things.

1. why does ShapeableImageView have `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute and refer to a style rather than just having `cornerFamily`, `cornerSize` attributes? (what is the point of using `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute if it is not inheriting anything?)
2. why those styles either inheriting empty parent or even inheriting nothing?
3. where to find sample code for ShapeableImageView? I tried to find it at Material Design github page like how [material Button](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md) is supposed to be used, but I wasn't able to find it.

Thanks in advance.